# Using Avro Julia Package

Tags: julia

It seems like there is some simple version mismatch occuring when trying to use Julia 1.0+ with this older package.

```
 pkg> add Avro
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Avro [cb912096]:
 Avro [cb912096] log:
 ├─possible versions are: 0.0.1-0.0.3 or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.0.1-0.0.3
 └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: uninstalled — no versions left
```

Is there a way to use Compat or to update the Avro package so it will work in Julia 1.0?

Comment: There seems to be an open pull request that updates the package to Julia 1.0+. You may want to add the package through [that PR](https://github.com/Hydrotoast/Avro.jl/pull/3).